# How to Append A element in array Cloud firestore in android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add my data in **cloud firestore array as list** but my data is overwrite it again and again store value at same index 0 can anyone help me how to store array as on next index without overwrite

```
viewHolder.binding.followButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        viewHolder.binding.followButton.setText("Requested");
        String receiverUid = users.getUid();
        String senderUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid();
        DocumentReference documentReference = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Requests").document(receiverUid);
        documentReference.update("FollowRequests",FieldValue.arrayUnion(senderUid)).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "RequestSend", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Request Not Send", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Your code is correct. What could be happening is that nothing is actually being overwriten, but since the array already contains that particular uid the `arrayUnion()` does nothing, as `arrayUnion()` does not add repeated values to an array. Can you confirm that you are not using the same value?

Comment: I am trying to add a new sender id every time but it overwrites my previous sender id which is stored in a firestore array at zero index

Comment: Well, then it should be working with the code you currently have. Could you share your firestore structure and a couple of examples of values (one existing and one new) to be added on that array?